# Map a file to memory without external libraries

Tags: ruby, linux

How can I memory map (`mmap`) an open file descriptor using Ruby *without using external libraries and without opening new files* (I cannot use DL library which opens static libraries)?

I have already tried:

```
address = syscall(NR_MMAP, 0, SIZE, prot, flag, fd, OFFSET)
```

But now I need to dereference an address. Is there a way to do it?

Is there another way to proceed without using `syscall`?

Comment: Please add WHY you want to do this. Aaron Peterson, the author of Nokogiri and a major Rails name, has code available. Why not piggyback on his gem?